# DataFrames Python How to loop a Cell A1 in Column A with Cell B2 Column B in Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

The table consists of 2 Columns in DataFrame. In first Column we have many products say there are A, B, C, D, E etc., Say the product A has been repeated thrice in Column A, and for every corresponding value of A there are 3 Date entries in Column B. How can I pick the first date and last date for A using Python in Pandas

```
Column_1 Column_2
A      1-1-2000
B      1-1-2001
C      1-1-2002
A      1-1-2003
B      1-1-2004
C      1-1-2005
A      1-1-2006
B      1-1-2007
C      1-1-2008
A      1-1-2009
B      1-1-2010
C      1-1-2011
A      1-1-2013
D      1-1-2015
F      1-1-2020
```

Data

Comment: can you please show the head of that df

Comment: First Column Header Name : Product ; Second Column Header Name : Date

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

`df.groupby('Column_1').agg({'Column_2': ['first', 'last']})`

```
          Column_2          
             first      last
Column_1                    
A         1-1-2000  1-1-2013
B         1-1-2001  1-1-2010
C         1-1-2002  1-1-2011
D         1-1-2015  1-1-2015
F         1-1-2020  1-1-2020
```

Comment: WOW. Yes. Thank you Kenan. Pl suggest where I can practice these ? Any resource of books do you recommend ?

Comment: Many places `medium.com` [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/python_pandas_groupby.htm) and many more. If that's all you need please accept the answer +1 so this question can be closed

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way I can bring the same result by writing a program using Lists or Tuples and Dictionaries ?? Your answer would be much helpful to me Mr Kenan?

Comment: Of course that would be the manual way, requiring you to iterate over the df and check first/last

Comment: Can you please help me with that code, in that way I will also learn a bit of python? I have tried using Lists but I was not successful  !! I can send the code that I have tried if you are interested to view it.

Comment: Sorry stackoverflow isn't really for that. It would be lengthy to go through that process. If your very new to python i suggest [datacamp](https://www.datacamp.com/) as a good start